# deleting directory in Bitrix CMS

Tags: content-management-system, directory, bitrix

How to delete directory from site structure in bitrix?

[image]

I found how to delete one file, but what about directory?

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about usage of Bitrix CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is very easy but not obviously:

in left sidebar go to Files and Folders and find the absolute path of you folder here.
So in this menu you can delete whole folder with all or not content.